# Display data in listview depending on the session of the user

Tags: android, session, android-intent, android-fragments

Is there's a way that get the data from the MySQL server database display in list view in android depending on the session of the user who log in to the application. the data will be sort depending on the user_id of the user.

this is may Login.java

```
public class Displayloginpage extends Activity {


Button loginbutton;
EditText usernameedittext,passwordedittext;
TextView tv, forgot;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displaylogin);

    // Session Manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());                


    loginbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);  
    usernameedittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameet);
    passwordedittext= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordet);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    forgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgottext);

    forgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alert();
        }
    });

    loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Displayloginpage.this, "", 
                    "Validating user...", true);

             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        login();                          
                    }
                  }).start();               
        }
    });

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void alert() {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
           Displayloginpage.this).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Forget Username/Password");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Please Contact Your School Administrator");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.fail);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}


void login(){
    try{            

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.100:80/ihatid/android/Attender/login_user.php"); 
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",usernameedittext.getText().toString().trim()));  
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",passwordedittext.getText().toString().trim())); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Displayloginpage.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String username = usernameedittext.getText().toString();
                    String password = passwordedittext.getText().toString();
                    session.createLoginSession(username, password);
                }
            });
            Displayloginpage.this.finish();
            Intent loginintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrawerMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginintent);
        }else{
            showAlert();                
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void showAlert(){
    Displayloginpage.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Displayloginpage.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
            builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       }
                   });                     
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();               
        }
    });
}
```

}

this is may main.java

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class Main extends         Fragment {

   public Main(){

    }


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false); 
    new GetUser().execute();

    return rootView;
 }
 class GetUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    //private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //String row_id = "1";
    String result=null;
    InputStream is=null;
    String line=null;
    String user = "user";



        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
   /*
    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Fragment myProfileFragment = null;
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading recipe profile. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
/*    
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

*/
        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */


        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread

            //String returnName, returnIngr, returnProc;


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    //int success;
                        String id = "1";
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",id));


                        try {
                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.100:80/ihatid/android/Attender/getattenderuser.php");
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            is = entity.getContent();
                            Log.e("pass 1", " connection success ");

                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                        }

                        try {
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                            (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            is.close();
                            result=sb.toString();
                            //Toast shit = Toast.makeText(MyProfileFragment.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            //shit.show();
                            Log.e("pass 2", " connection success ");

                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
                        }

                        try {
                            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                            Log.d("User details",json_data.toString());
                            int code;


                            code=1;

                            JSONArray userObj = json_data.getJSONArray("user"); 
                            if(code==1) {



                                String up_name = "schoolname";
                                String up_add = "name";
                                String up_eadd = "licenseno";

                                for (int i = 0; i < userObj.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject getrecipe = userObj.getJSONObject(i);



                                TextView txtName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.register);
                                TextView txtAdd = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
                                TextView txtEAdd = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.license); 


                                 txtName.setText(getrecipe.getString(up_name));
                                 txtAdd.setText(getrecipe.getString(up_add));
                                 txtEAdd.setText(getrecipe.getString(up_eadd));

                                }
                            }
                            else if(code==0){
                                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MyProfileFragment.this, "Error: code is equal to 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                //toast.show();
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                            //e.printStackTrace();
                        }      
                    }
            });
            return null;
        }

        private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}
}
```

this is my session.

```
public class SessionManager {
// Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor for Shared preferences
Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

// User name (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "username";

// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

// Constructor
@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
public SessionManager(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

/**
 * Create login session
 * */
public void createLoginSession(String username, String password){
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing name in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, username);

    // Storing email in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, password);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}   

/**
 * Check login method wil check user login status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else won't do anything
 * */
public void checkLogin(){
    // Check login status
    if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Displayloginpage.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

}



/**
 * Get stored session data
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // user name
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

    // user email id
    user.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pref.getString(KEY_PASSWORD, null));

    // return user
    return user;
}

/**
 * Clear session details
 * */
public void logoutUser(){
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, Displayloginpage.class);
    // Closing all the Activities
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Staring Login Activity
    _context.startActivity(i);
}

/**
 * Quick check for login
 * **/
// Get Login State
public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}
}
```

my liistvier.java

```
public class Listattendance extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList;
SessionManager session;
// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_student =  "http://192.168.1.101:80/ihatid/android/attender/allstudent.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_STUDENT = "student";
private static final String TAG_SNO = "studentno";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_LAT = "latitude";
private static final String TAG_LONG = "longitude";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray students = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listattendance);

    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());  
    session.checkLogin();
    // Hashmap for ListView
    studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread




    // Get listview
    //ListView lv = getListView();
    //lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        //@Override
        //public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        //      int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            //String sno = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.studentno)).getText().toString();
            //String names = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            // Starting new intent
            //Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),   .class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            //in.putExtra(TAG_SNO, sno);
            //in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, names);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            //startActivity(in);
//  }
//});
    new LoadAllstudents().execute();
}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
//@Override
//protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
//  if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
//      Intent intent = getIntent();
//      finish();
//      startActivity(intent);
//  }

//}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllstudents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Listattendance.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Students. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_student, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Student: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                students = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STUDENT);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = students.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    //String studentid = c.getString(TAG_SNO);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    //map.put(TAG_SNO, studentid);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    studentList.add(map);
                }
            } else {


                Toast.makeText(Listattendance.this, "No student found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                //      NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
            //  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            //  startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        Listattendance.this, studentList,
                        R.layout.listview_item, new String[] { 
                                TAG_NAME },
                        new int[] { R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

After the user login. all i want is to display the users info on the main.java. by the way i'm using Drawer navigation in my android application. Then, when i click the listActivity button this will direct to the xml that will display the data in listview from the database.

My problem is I don't know how to display the user information and display the data depending on the session of the user. Help pleas...thanks in advance... I'm just a beginner...

my php file...this is for getting the user datails

```
$response = array();


require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/ihatid/android/Connection/connection.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("select a.ATTENDER_NO AS ATTENDERNO,CONCAT(a.FIRSTNAME ',' a.MIDDLENAME ',
        ' a.LASTNAME) AS NAME, a.LICENSE_NO, s.SCHOOLNAME, a.LICENSE_NO, 
        s.SCHOOLNAME AS SCHOOLNAME, s.SCHOOL_ID from 
        attender a, school_admin s, vehicle v, vehicle_sched b 
        where a.ATTENDER_NO = b.ATTENDER_NO 
        AND v.PLATE_NO = b.PLATE_NO
        AND s.SCHOOL_ID = v.SCHOOL_ID
        AND a.USERNAME = '$username'
        AND a.PASSWORD = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["attender"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $attender = array();
    $attender["schoolname"]= $row["SCHOOLNAME"];
    $attender["attenderno"]= $row["ATTENDERNO"];
    $attender["name"] = $row["NAME"];
    $attender["licenseno"] = $row["LICENSE_NO"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["attender"], $attender);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No attender/s found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

This is the php for login

```
<?php

//Login code details 
$reponse = array();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/ihatid/android/Connection/connection.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// get user name from users table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ATTENDER_NO FROM attender where USERNAME = '$username' && PASSWORD  = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "User Found";
} else {
// user name and or password is incorrect
// invalid login
echo "User not Found";
}
?>
```

this is for the displaying data in the listview

```
<?php


$response = array();


require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/ihatid/android/Connection/connection.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();


$username = $_GET["name"];
$password = $_GET["email"];
// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT student.STUDENT_NO, student.FIRSTNAME, 
            vehicle.PLATE_NO, CONCAT(attender.FIRSTNAME , attender.MIDDLENAME, attender.LASTNAME)      AS NAME,
            parent.FIRSTNAME, parent.LATITUDE AS LATITUDE, parent.LONGITUDE AS LONGITUDE
            FROM student, vehicle, vehicle_sched, attender, student_has_parent, parent
            WHERE student.PLATE_NO = vehicle.PLATE_NO
            AND vehicle.PLATE_NO = vehicle_sched.PLATE_NO
            AND vehicle_sched.ATTENDER_NO = attender.ATTENDER_NO
            AND student.STUDENT_NO = student_has_parent.STUDENT_NO
            AND student_has_parent.PARENT_NO = parent.PARENT_NO
            AND attender.FIRSTNAME = '$usename'
            AND student.ENROLL_STATUS = 'active'") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["student"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $student = array();
    $student["studentno"]= $row["STUDENT_NO"];
    $student["name"] = $row["NAME"];
    $student["latitude"] = $row["LATITUDE"];
    $student["longitude"] = $row["LONGITUDE"];



    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["student"], $student);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No student/s found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: any help or suggestion or tips..will help me..thnx..

Comment: why don't you store the details in SQLite? then depending on the username retrieve the details from SQLite and display.

Comment: how can i do that? if the user type his name and password it should be save in SQLite? is thats the logic?

Comment: Don't store the username and password in SQLite. If you are getting any unique ID for each users from server then store it in SQLite along with other details you want to display, then access the details of that user by passing the ID.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will try it on. but can you guys give a tips on where to put it based on my code ^^

Comment: Open the SQLite in onPostExecute method and then insert the details.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to implementing this. I'm not going to describe how to implement each of these steps in detail - I just want to provide you an overview of what you should/need to do.

1. I see that you're using JSON, which is great. However, you should create a class called `Student` and add the same fields to the class as you have in your JSON. Then you should populate each student object with the JSON data.

   Doing so will make your life a lot easier - you'll get compiler errors for any typos you make, and your code will be more maintainable.
2. Once you have an ArrayList of `Student` objects, you'll need to create an `ArrayAdapter`. Android uses the `ArrayAdapter` class extensively for ListViews; you should definitely have a good understanding of how they work before proceeding.

   I highly recommend that you follow this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Once you have the ArrayAdapter setup, it's very easy to update the data for the `ListView`. Simply call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.